# Build Failed with an an exception

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

[***enter image description here***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLlG6.png)

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.

> java.nio.file.FileSystemException: D:\Course\Flutter_Projects\dating_app\build\app\intermediates\merged_java_res\debug\out.jar: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: close everything and a simple restart will work I guess !

Comment: Open android studio->open avd and select your device right click it and click on wipe data or cold boot now and then run your app

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this from an IDE, try simple clean builds or invalidate the cache option found in Intellij IDE's. Try closing the Android Studio completely as well (surprisingly solves some times).

If you have a git folder, you might also try `git clean -fdX`.